# is it possible to use OleDbDataAdapter to query excel line number

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledbdataadapter

is it possible to use OleDbDataAdapter to query excel line number ?

the picture is here
[image: screen shot]

```
OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand("Select *, [Sheet1$].ExcelLineNumber From [Sheet1$]", objConn);

OleDbDataAdapter objDatAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
objDatAdap.SelectCommand = objCmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
objDatAdap.Fill(ds);
```

the result should be

```
 Column A | column B | Column C | ExcelLineNumber
      1        pong         13              5
      2        pong          2              6
```

............

is is possible ? if not, is there any way to get around with it ??  I've been trying a lot of things but it might consume too much performance

Comment: AFAIK, when you query from a spreadsheet, you'll get all the rows, not only where you have data. This means that the row index at the DataTable is the index at the file.

Comment: Not really. The driver ignores the empty rows and columns.

Comment: @ZoranCausev I'm using the provider `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`, and it does not remove empty rows or columns

Comment: Also, I query using the position of the column, like `SELECT F1, F9, F10, F11, F12, F13  FROM [SpreadSheet$]`, where `F1` is **A** and so on. Using OP's example, the query would be `SELECT F3, F4, F5 FROM [Sheet1$]`

Comment: thank you vrry much Adnre. just like Zoran Causev said, inspite of using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, somehow it does ignore the space -  so using the line number by using table index cannot be done.

Comment: also getting around by using the position might be a little bit harsh for the system but thanks anyway.